# iOS is forward compatible or backwad compatible

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, ios5

I would like to know whether iOS apps are forward or backward compatible.
If I design an app in iOS4 can it be run on iOS5.

Android is forward compatible, can be built on SDK 1.6 and the same app can be run on newer versions of Android Operating Systems.

How about the iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is. But you should always check your apps when a new version of the framework is released.

I remember that some of my old apps crashed when I updated to iOS 5.

The question have been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167502/is-ios-4-generally-backwards-compatible).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would work. Although you should check if certain methods have been deprecated, or changed in some way, so for instance you might be able to use a method on iOS4 and that method been changed in some way in iOS5. The same is true for backward compatibility, certain classes only appeared on iOS5, and you will have crashes when using those on iOS4. Bottom line: **test on both version your application**.

There a couple of question/answers regarding this topic:

[Pitfalls when writing an iOS app supporting iOS 3.1.3 and iOS 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839847/pitfalls-when-writing-an-ios-app-supporting-ios-3-1-3-and-ios-4-x)

[Recommended way to support backward/forward compatibility in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954342/recommended-way-to-support-backward-forward-compatibility-in-iphone-app)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, this is true. There are some exceptions though, and the only way to be sure is to test the app on different versions.

A big difference with Android though is that most handsets are up-to-date with the latest OS, so if you are starting a new project you should probably consider targeting iOS5.

Comment: I think you meant "A big difference with iOS".